# elm327 for Android

Tags: android, bluetooth, driver

I would like to develop an Android app for elm327 to test vehicles ECUs.

If I use the bluetooth connection between the Android device and the ELM327 device, **do I need to install a driver on the android app?** or is it enough to just use the built-in Bluetooth Classes that Google provides within the Android platform and use the AT commands according to the ELM327 specifications?

Please help guys!!!

Comment: Sounds like a cool idea. Never heard of anything like this so you may have to blaze a trail.

Answer (score 3):

It all depends on what you are using as the ELM327 device.

If it is USB based and you are connecting it to a bluetooth adapter, then more then likely you are going to have to install a driver for the USB device.

If you are building your own or buying one that is physically a rs232 port/bluetooth adapter, or even an ELM327 bluetooth module (almost all use a logic based rs232 as opposed to hardware based), as long as you set the bluetooth settings in the android to treat it as a serial device, then you should be able to directly connect to it without a driver.

As long as you are just doing diagnostics and not trying to "TUNE" the PCM you should be fine with setting the Baud rate permanently at 38400 and just leaving it there.

When you start to use it for Tuning there are other issues/concerns when using bluetooth, one is a disconnection during flashing that could "brick" the PCM and another is forcing the 5 bits per second during the initial handshake, seed/key for accessing.

Sounds like a good project though, good luck.

I am not an android programmer by any means but I do have a lot of experience in building ELM327/PC interfaces so if you get stuck with something with the ELM327 and communicating with the PCM, let me know, I should be able to answer it for you, or point you in the right direction for answers if I can't.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. It's a very useful answer - I've got two questions - what do you mean when you mention 'logic based' vs 'hardware based' RS232, and what do you mean by 'PCM'. Also, please feel free to check out electronics.stackexchange.com - I think you might enjoy it.

Comment: Thanks Justin. Do you do if the elm327 supports body and chassis modules as well. I know that pcm is supported for sure.